# How to add and align figure and texts like that

Tags: tables, align

Please show me how I can do that. And I want to use many times. Help me write a macro so that I can use every time I need.

For example,

```
\begin{question} 
    Texts in the question field. 
\end{question}
```

[image: the figure in the left, the texts in the right (with justify aligned)]

**Update**: This question is already solved by other linked questions.

Comment: Related: [Pretty formatting for warning and info blocks](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53245/5764)

Comment: great, do i need to delete this post?

Comment: Related: [Rounded box with image and text](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/102295/5764); [Need to left align referenced image in `mdframed` Info box](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/116578/5764)

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to create Highlight Boxes in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66820/5764)

Comment: If the posted link(s) do not solve your request, please give some feedback.

Comment: No, they are exactly what I need. They are very helpful :)